# TRPC getAll not updating

Tags: next.js, trpc

I am using Theo's T3 stack with the app directory and Nextjs 14. I created 2 mutations. One to add a user and the other to get list of users. I add the user normally in the form then

```
onSuccess:
router.push("/users");
```

In the users page.tsx which shows a table, I get the list of users:

```
const usersList= await api.users.getAll.query();
```

However, I do not see the newly created users. I have to refresh the page to update the users list.

I even tried adding

```
void ctx.users.getAll.invalidate();
```

in the onSuccess before router.push but did not do anything

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found for this is to have

```
router.refresh()
router.replace('/users')
```

That way you will always get the new data